# actionscript 3.0 function mouseevent event handler

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, event-handling, mouseevent, addchild

I have a function that uses a mouse event and it removes and adds things onto the stage:

```
beginBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bgnListener);
function bgnListener (event:MouseEvent) {
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, setScreen);
    removeChild(beginBut);
    removeChild(myWord);

    healthBar.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, healthLose);
    ball.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveBall);
    myGem.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, addGem);
    myScore.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, scoreCount);
    healthBar.width+=1000;

}
```

However after some other things happen, I need this event to occur again. I have already 
added beginBut but when I use

```
beginBut.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, bgnListener);
```

the event adds and removes the things automatically when the function that adds `beginBut` back occurs and not when I actually click on `beginBut`. I have also tried

```
bgnListener();
```

but it says that there is the wrong number of arguments. I already searched all over and I can't seem to fix this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `bgnListener()` like you are now, you'll get an argument mismatch error because the function is expecting to receive a `MouseEvent`.

If you want to be able to call `bgnListener()` on its own like that, you can define a default value for your argument `event`, which can be `null`:

```
function bgnListener(event:MouseEvent = null)
{
    // ...
}
```